# Should I force my random generated password to always contain uppercase, lowercase, and digit?

Tags: security

I am looking at a piece of code which generates random passwords. The default password length is 6; the code picks one upper-case letter, one lower-case letter, and a digit, and then picks the rest of the characters randomly from all three categories. Finally, the characters are shuffled.

What I'm wondering about is if forcing the password to contain at least one uppercase, one lowercase, and one digit, actually makes the password weaker. It does reduce the number of possible password combinations quite a bit, so I would be inclined to say dropping this requirement would give me passwords that have a have a higher search space.

What do you folks think about this?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29836/what-are-good-requirements-for-a-password

Comment: Yes it does make it weaker. If you are brute forcing the password, you can trim out guesses based on these rules (for example if your guess includes 5 non numerical digits, you know the last digit must be a number). Anything that limits the number of potential bits is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that there were only two rules for password policies, one related to minimum length and another one related to character mixing and complexity (case-sensitivity rules, mixing digits, special characters etc).

Let's now assume that we stick to an N-digit password policy, eg in your case, a system that every password will consist of 6 characters exactly. As we can't apply the 1st rule (size is predetermined now), we are left with the second rule option only. Do we apply it?

It's a fact that all variations of this 2nd rule will actually decrease the maximum entropy for the passwords (possible combinations are less now). Brute force attacks will exhaust the available space in less time; especially if N is too small, this may have some impact (BTW 6 is too too small). Somehow we could say that expert users, where by default use complex passwords, are not benefited from such rules.

BUT, **you need to choose these rules for the average user who usually picks an easy guess**. A good cracker will use dictionary attacks, rainbow tables (especially if you are not using salting in your password, usually hash-like, function) and then go to more extensive brute force attacks.

With this rule, it's mainly the dictionary attacks you are protecting your users from and we all know by the time we were young who is the average user... we've all gone through that! Anyway, you have to increase N and ask yourself who is gonna use your system.